# MyISAM vs InnoDB for Forums

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I want to design a forum script with MySql. Which database engine would have better performance? MyISAM or InnoDB ?

Comment: Asking questions about what engine performs better when you have provided almost no detail will likely result in your question being closed as "shopping list".  Add details about your scenario, please!

Comment: Nor MyISAM or InnoDB belongs to me. I want know the experiences of experts. I think all of programmers interesting on database performances. The forum script is an explanatory  for specific programmings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Always use InnoDB by default.

- **InnoDB is durable and crash-safe.**  Your database will not be corrupted in a crash.  MyISAM is very susceptible to data corruption.  This should be a more important consideration than performance -- unless you don't really care if you lose your data.
- **InnoDB caches both data and indexes in RAM.**  MyISAM caches only indexes in RAM.  So if you have enough RAM, queries will almost certainly be faster in InnoDB.
- **InnoDB is the default.**  It has been MySQL's default storage engine since MySQL 5.5 (circa 2010).
- **InnoDB continues to improve.**  MyISAM is not being improved.  All of the storage engine engineering work is going into InnoDB.
- **InnoDB is faster anyway.**  Here's a performance comparison from way back in 2007 that shows InnoDB beats MyISAM in most tests:  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/

  Of course, benchmarks results show the performance of the benchmark, not the performance of your application.  If you want a more authoritative answer, you should run [sysbench](https://launchpad.net/sysbench) to test your database on your hardware.

There are cases where MyISAM is faster, but these cases are becoming more and more rare.  For instance, doing table-scans.  Or `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table`.  But you should treat InnoDB as the default storage engine choice until you can demonstrate a case where MyISAM beats it.

Comment: + Foreign Keys.

Comment: @ypercube, of course, but that's not as relevant to the OP's question about performance.  Foreign keys can even be a disadvantage for scalability because of extra S-locks.

Comment: Yes, it's not exactly relevant to the question. Can you pop on [the Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179) if you have a minute to spare?

Comment: +1 on the full InnoDB pitch since MyISAM can't cache a lick of data anywhere (as shown by your second point)

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin . Your answer is complete and explanatory.

Comment: Is this true even if I have only one table without foreign keys?

Comment: @Huseyin, as I said above, to be certain you have to benchmark your application and compare InnoDB vs. MyISAM.  I'm describing a general rule for preferring InnoDB over MyISAM, but there are always exception cases in any technology choice.  In other words, it depends what you're doing with it.